# How can I get the path of a given dll in java?

Tags: java, dll

I have a .dll for example "example.dll" and I know that this dll is in one  of the paths specified in java.library.path, there is a simple way to get the dll's path without executing a cicle on this list of paths?

Comment: That sounds simple to me. Its one loop and one check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't. The DLL's are not a Java's fully supported "type" so I am not sure even about the GAC approach. You have to iterate and find.

Answer (score 2):

A loop sounds simple to me.

```
for(String dir: System.getProperty("java.library.path").split(File.pathSeparator))
    if(new File(dir, "example.dll").isFile())
        // found directory
```